# Composing Functions Leads to StackOverflow

Tags: scala

[Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) lists the following example as to how composing functions can lead to a `StackOverflowError`.

```
scala> val f = (x: Int) => x
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val g = List.fill(100000)(f).foldLeft(f)(_ compose _)
g: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> g(42)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

As the book explains, `g` is a composite function that has 100,000 functions where each one calls the next.

Since `foldLeft` is tail-recursive, why does this StackOverflowError occur? How, if at all, are tail-recursion and StackOverflow's related?

When (as it's expanded) the second argument `(B, A) => B` of `foldLeft`, `((acc, elem) => acc.compose(elem))`, doesn't each fold step result in composing only 2 functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since foldLeft is tail-recursive, why does this StackOverflowError occur? How, if at all, are tail-recursion and StackOverflow's related?
>
> When (as it's expanded) the second argument (B, A) => B of foldLeft, ((acc, elem) => acc.compose(elem)), doesn't each fold step result in composing only 2 functions?

Note that the fold *itself* (i.e. the line `val g = ...`) doesn't overflow stack. However, `g` ends up being defined effectively as `f(f(...(x)))` and therefore you need 100000 stack frames to evaluate `g(42)` which obviously does overflow.

Answer (score 5):

It's not because of `foldLeft` or `compose` itself. It's because `g(x) = f(f(f(...(x)))`.